# Problem with E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android

I have some problem with

"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    RecyclerView postRecyclerView ;
    PostAdapter postAdapter ;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
    List<Post> postList;




    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        postRecyclerView  = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.postRV);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        postRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
        return fragmentView ;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Get List Posts from the database

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                postList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot postsnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Post post = postsnap.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(post) ;



                }

                postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),postList);
                postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

PostAdapter

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<Post> mData ;


    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_post_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(row);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getPicture()).into(holder.imgPost);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getUserPhoto()).into(holder.imgPostProfile);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView imgPost;
        ImageView imgPostProfile;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_title);
            imgPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_img);
            imgPostProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_profile_img);
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong I already set adapter  in this line.
postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),postList);
postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate adapter attachment and data update of the recycler.

Create and attach the adapter in fragment's `onCreateView` (initialize empty list inside the adapter):

```
postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity());
```

Add function to `PostAdapter` to update the date and notify that the data was changed:

```
private void updateData(List<Post> newData) {
    mData.clear();
    mData.addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You can optimize `notifyDataSetChanged()` and notify exactly what items were changed (other `notify*` functions).